# How is this array initialization happening?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Comma Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/c-comma-operator)

I am initializing an array with

```
int main()
{
    int arr[3]= { (1,3), 2, 4 };
    cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << " " << arr[2] << endl;
}
```

I thought it would give a compile time error but it is running fine. The array is initialized with values `3,2,4` and output is also `3 2 4`.

Can someone explain what is happening here ?

Comment: A vote to reopen should include an explanation of some way this question is different from the duplicate.  If you can't think of one, don't reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the comma operator there. Basically, the expression:

```
1,7
```

will evaluate `1` but "return" 7.

That particular form you have (as well as mine above) is not that useful but you can do things like:

```
x = a++, 1;
```

to both increment `a` and set `x` to 1 (the usefulness comes from side effects).

You will have seen this before without necessarily realising it:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 4; i++, j++) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The same reason why:

```
int x = (1,3);
assert(x==3);
```

happens.

That's how the comma operator works. It "*returns*" the last expression, while (potentially) evaluating both.